# what css and jquery used to change color of background

Tags: jquery, css

i just came across this page and liked the way of changing color continously. I checked source code but didnot find script used to change colors . http://www.attn.com/vote

Can anybody point me to right direction. What script used to create page with changing background colors?

Comment: you can change background color by adding removing class by using toggleClass() depending on the need

Comment: This is not a script but a CSS animation

Answer (score 1):

On that page it's done via css3 animations. this is their exact code:

```
.page--voter-reg {
    animation: 17s ease 0s normal none infinite running fifty50;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(90deg, #ff3e41, #38618c) repeat scroll 0 0 / 400% 400%;
    padding: 120px 0;
}
@keyframes fifty50 {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a little aproach...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 setInterval(function() {
    $('body').animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 300)
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'green' }, 300); 
    }, 1000);

 });
```

[check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/theSifter/yR6jc/)